# SpriteKit is unable to load a previously used resource

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have an app that I'm making with Xcode 5.1 and I have a resource (score.mp3) that I can use a few hundred times in the app, before it crashes with this error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Failed to Load Resource',
>   reason: 'Resource score.mp3 can not be loaded'

Does anyone have any clue what I can do. I copied it to the destination folder and it worked fine until around 250-300 times but then I got this error. Also I am using sprite kit, if that is important. I am playing the sound like this:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playerSoundFileNamed:@"score.mp3" waitForCompletion:YES]];
```

Comment: Same here, Xcode 12.3, tvOS 14. Sound plays correctly hundreds of times, but suddenly `SKAction: Error loading sound resource: "click_01.mp3"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a `SKAction` that represents playing the laser sound, and reuse that object so the audio file is only loaded once.

I hope `playSoundFileNamed:` does not reload the file every time you call it but your crash shows that it does it at least after some time.

Comment: Great! Good to hear it. Can you please accept my answer? :)